# installing MUSCLE on windows

Tags: perl, cmd, installation

I want to install the lates version of MUSCLE downloaded from http://www.drive5.com/muscle/downloads.htm

named muscle3.8.31_i86win32.exe . As the guidelines 
http://www.drive5.com/muscle/manual/install.html
says I have to write the below line in the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\muscle3.8.31_i86win32 -in seqs.fa -out seqs.afa
```

However, I faced this error:

> MUSCLE v3.8.31 by Robert C. Edgar
>
> http://www.drive5.com/muscle This software is donated to the public
>   domain. Please cite: Edgar, R.C. Nucleic Acids Res 32(5), 1792-97.
>
> *** ERROR ***  Cannot open 'seqs.fa' errno=2

I am sure the file exists in the mentioned directory, but I don't why has this happened and how can I fix it. Any idea?

Comment: @ikegami the mentioned directory and the current directory are the same

Answer (score 0):

The program is reporting that the OS reported that the file doesn't exist. (That's what errno 2 is.)

Testing reveals that relatives paths are resolved relative to the current work directory as expected.

So, your operating system is saying there's no file named `seqs.fa` in the current work directory.

Double check the name of the file you have. Keep in mind that File Explorer hides known file extensions by default so using `dir` would be more reliable.